# Using tikzlibrary calligraphy for braces with a minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I wanted to put a brace from the excellent TikZ library `calligraphy` on one side of a minipage. I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},remember picture]%
    \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\strut};}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\noindent\tikzmark{A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis est quis arcu pretium imperdiet. Donec facilisis pharetra posuere. Proin auctor purus vel nunc ultrices, et mollis est ultrices. Nulla blandit finibus lacinia. Nam congue ante et libero ornare, et feugiat ipsum cursus. Quisque tincidunt a urna at vestibulum.\tikzmark{B}
\end{minipage}

\tikz[decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=6pt},remember picture,overlay,ultra thick]%
\draw ($(A.north) - (6pt,0)$) -- ($(A |- B.south) - (6pt,0)$);

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Example of failed braces with minipage.]

No brace. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to say in `\draw[decorate] ...;` otherwise it draws an ordinary line ... So, try the following correction of your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},remember picture]%
    \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\strut};}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\noindent\tikzmark{A}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis est quis arcu pretium imperdiet. Donec facilisis pharetra posuere. Proin auctor purus vel nunc ultrices, et mollis est ultrices. Nulla blandit finibus lacinia. Nam congue ante et libero ornare, et feugiat ipsum cursus. Quisque tincidunt a urna at vestibulum.\tikzmark{B}
\end{minipage}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay,ultra thick,
      decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror,
                  raise=6pt, amplitude=6pt}]%
\draw[decorate] (A.north) -- (A |- B.south);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- that's perfect. Also the `raise=6pt` is a nice touch.